# Remove trailing characters of a String

Tags: java

I need to trim the name of a file to get only the name in meaning, if that make any sense. For example, I have this file:
`myFileName_XYZ_2901_20.dat` and I just want to extract the name of it: `myFileName_XYZ`. 
I have this for now:

```
    String word = myFileName.replaceAll("([^_.*\0-9 ])", "");
```

but when I debug it gives me: `__201901_20.`

How can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Is all the names in this format?

Comment: You can always append `"dat"` to the string and replace the new string with the empty string. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove the last part with digits and underscores but not the extension

```
String word = myFileName.replaceAll("(_\\d+_\\d+)", "");
```

result

> myFileName_XYZ.dat

Comment: This answer assumes that "myFileName_XYZ" part will never contain number patterns. If that assumption is valid, no problem, but if it isn't then a filename like this `"myFile_11_22_XYZ_2901_20.dat"` could be turned into `"myFile_XYZ.dat"` instead of the intended output of `"myFile_11_22_XYZ.dat"`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regular expression for this; just take everything before the second `_` character in the `String`:

```
String word = myFileName.substring(0, 
    myFileName.indexOf('_', myFileName.indexOf('_') + 1));
```

Output:

```
myFileName_XYZ
```

Note that this assumes both `myFileName` and `XYZ` won't contain any `_` characters.

Answer (score 1):

Patterns might be what you need ultimately, but if the patterns you intend *remove* end up being part of the filename part that you want to *keep*, you will have unexpected results.

If it's always the same pattern at the end – `_XXXX_YY.dat` – you could just remove that fixed length of 12 characters from the end. This would print "myFileName_XYZ":

```
String s = "myFileName_XYZ_2901_20.dat";
int length = s.length() - 12;
System.out.println(s.substring(0, length));
```

Comment: the file name doesn't change, what changes is the numbers. I need to leave some room for implementation in the future, that's why I need the pattern. Thank you

Comment: @Arturo If the file name does not change you could just do the opposite then and `substring` the beginning characters until the name ends, not that I think this is necessarily the best method.